# Не работает редактор ER-Diagram JPA IDEA

Tags: java, база-данных, intellij-idea, jpa, er-diagram

У меня после добавления сущности в ER-Diagram, который через java persistence, просто не отображаются сущности. Раньше была такая же шняга, только можно было в верху кнопочки поклацать и оно появится, а сейчас так вообще не работает. Что делать? Я добавлял поддержку Java persistence, а перед этим eclipselink jpa добавил ну и mysql соотвественно. И проверял подключение к БД - работает.

Файл persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
  <persistence-unit name="ShopPU">
    <class>main.data.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="student"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="123"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Скриншоты:

1. Создаю сущность

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решений Этой проблемы я не нашёл, но при создании класов, можно прост оперед ними дописать @Entity и они будут отображаться в ER-Diagram и дальше можете работать с ними как хотите